# How to join two tables in this example

Tags: sql

I got a problem getting records out of two tables correctly.

I need to get a list in which every device and its software is linked.

Hard to explain what my goal is, but i hope you will understand my Example.

Example:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044752/sql-mapping-between-multiple-tables You can use mapping. Check this link please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a join with multiple instances of table2

```
select b.name,c.name
from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.targetid=b.objectid
inner join table2 c on a.assignedid=c.objectid
```

Comment: Perfect, just had to change the SELECT a.name to b.name.

Answer (score 0):

JOIN the `Table2` two times with `Table1` and add the proper alias names will solve in your request.

The working query is:

```
SELECT T2.Name AS ComputerName, T3.Name AS SoftwareName
FROM Table1 T1
JOIN Table2 T2 T2.ObjectId = T1.TargetId
JOIN Table2 T3 T3.ObjectId = T1.AssignedId
```